# Send email through Constant Contact API

Tags: php, api, email, constantcontact

I am trying to use the Constant Contact API to do two things,

1: Take the name, phone, and email a user submits and add them to my constant contact account. (I got this working)

2: Take the user I just added, or even take just the email that is submitted and send them an email that is setup in constant contact.

I am currently unable to find a way to do this. Is this not possible with their API yet?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could either trigger the welcome email when you send the contact into Constant Contact, or you could assign the contact to a list that has been (or will be) sent the email you want to send them. Then schedule the email through the API. Using the existing welcome email that you can trigger is the more simple option.

When you send the contact to us, add the query parameter "action_by=ACTION_BY_VISITOR" to the URL you're sending the contact to (should be https://api.constantcontact.com/...). That will trigger the welcome email using the V2 (JSON) API. The SDK's Constant Contact built have an optional parameter you can set to 'true' that triggers the welcome email for new contacts. You can find and edit the welcome email if you login to your account and go to Contacts>>Sign-up Tools.

I hope that helps. If not, email us at webservices at constantcontact.com.

Best Regards,

Shannon Wallace